# Parallel make (gmake) execution order

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, gnu-make, order-of-execution

I have a makefile with many independent targets, each of which depends on one intermediate target.  Here is an example simplified makefile:

```
.PHONY: %.world %.hello

all: 0.world 1.world 2.world 3.world 4.world 5.world 6.world

%.world: %.hello
    @echo $@

%.hello:
    @echo $@

.INTERMEDIATE: %.hello
```

When I run make serially, it processes in the following order:

```
0.hello
0.world
1.hello
1.world
2.hello
2.world
3.hello
3.world
4.hello
4.world
5.hello
5.world
6.hello
6.world
```

But when I run with `-j2`, it runs *all* the intermediate files first, *then* the final ones:

```
0.hello
1.hello
2.hello
3.hello
4.hello
5.hello
6.hello
0.world
1.world
2.world
3.world
4.world
5.world
6.world
```

Both orderings are correct, but when processing many 100's of targets, I'd rather have the final files (`*.world`) sooner rather than waiting for *all* the intermediate files.  Is there any way to tweak the execution ordering, such that it would execute more like this:

```
0.hello
1.hello
0.world
1.world
2.hello
3.hello
2.world
3.world
4.hello
5.hello
4.world
5.world
6.hello
6.world
```

I know I could artificially enforce any generic ordering with dependencies, but I need a more general solution since I'm working with pattern rules and 100's of auto-generated targets.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no way you can change this behavior.  Make walks the graph in one direction and it doesn't start over until it's done.  Even if it sees that some prerequisite has finished building it will keep going through the graph until it's done, before restarting at the beginning and building things which are now ready to be built.